# Saving image using fs.writeFile

Tags: node.js, image, axios, fs

I'm trying to save an image using node's file-system that I got from https://picsum.photos/ but the file that is getting written is not what I'm expecting it to be.

```js
const axios = require('axios');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('file-system');

axios.get('https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300')
  .then((data) => {
    fs.writeFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../assets/test/test1.jpg'), data.data, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        throw err;
      }
      console.log('file save successfully');
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

[image: This is what the file results as]

Comment: In what format are the images sent from picsum?

Answer (score 4):

The data is probably being returned with the wrong encoding, as none is specified - most likely as text instead of as a binary stream, as the `responseType` is `'json'` by default. There is an example of writing an image to disk with an axios request on the [docs](https://github.com/axios/axios), in which `responseType` is set to `stream` and the given stream is piped to a writeStream. This is probably the kind of approach you'll need.

Below is the code example given on the docs:

> ```
> // GET request for remote image
> axios({
>   method: 'get',
>   url: 'https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300',
>   responseType: 'stream'
> })
>   .then(function (response) {
>     response.data.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('ada_lovelace.jpg'))
>   });
> ```

If you want to use `writeFile` still, you can set `responseType: 'arraybuffer'` instead, and pass the given buffer to `fs.writeFile`.